# VirtualBox - show mouse

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox

How do you show the mouse in virtual box (I am emulating a mobile device, it doesn't show the mouse which makes it difficult to use)

Comment: We need more details.  I'm assuming you are running with Ubuntu as the host, which version? And what is your guest OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Presume you mean **Android X86**. You have two Options

While your V-Machine is starting Up, go to the VM menu bar (Machine) and choose the **"Mouse Integration"** option. Then you click on the VM machine Screen. Either a window Popup will be displayed to say **"Capture"** so click on this option or the mouse pointer will hide from the Main screen. When the VM ice Finishes starting Up You should see the Mouse inside the V-Machine screen.

Alternatively place your mouse pointer on the VM screen and use **(right Control+I)** on the keyboard to capture the mouse.